# Transform each iteration of an array modifier within defined limits

Tags: python, modeling, modifiers

i am currently trying out some rendering for the first time (i was trying to model a pile of paper)

Used a plane, added a solidify modifier (don't judge, i was just messing around with some mods), added a array mod with a relative offset of z=1,2 (i wanted to be able to see the small spaces between each piece of paper, didn't work out though)

Now i wanted to randomly rotate each iteration with max 30 degrees and min -30 degrees so that the pile of paper would look realistic.
So far i tried a limit rotation constraint, simple deform mod and the object offset in the array mod, but none can achieve the result i'm looking for.
Any tips ? 
This is what I got so far. 
[image: Cards]

The uppermost card was rotated manually and manually editing 100 cards is not an option for me.

and i was planing to use thick paper, so thosehanging down edges are not required for this project (may inform myself about them sometime later on)
found a tut for another program, don't know how to use the mentioned steps in blender
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jm_ENqq-lwI

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure each sheet is a separate object. If it's not : in edit mode, press `P` -> separate by loose parts.
- Make sure each object has a decent center
- Select all sheets -> Object -> Transform -> Randomize transform

Select delta, an make sure only "rotation" is checked.

[image]

Comment: how would i go about limiting the rotation then ?
i want the rotation to be around the z-axis with about -30 to 30 degrees.
there are 100 seperate planes then.

Comment: You can control each axis... just set rotation X and Y to 0.

Comment: worked out perfectly by using a constraitn to limit z axis rotation. thx.